# assembly code which output to LCD screen fixing

Tags: assembly, x86

I have an assembly code that output to a LCD screen, I don't know how to use assembly language. But this is the code:

```
;  Clicking button saves & builds using commands:
;    nasm -f elf -g -F stabs evil.asm
;    ld -o evil evil.o
section .data
Snippet: db "@E9>06G@Q:CN3C57I<)<)*"
SnipLen: equ $-Snippet
section .text
global _start
_start:
        nop
        mov ecx,Snippet
        mov edx,SnipLen
        mov eax,6
DoMore: add byte [ecx],af
        inc ecx
        inc eax
        dec edx
        jnz DoMore
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        sub ecx,SnipLen
        mov edx,SnipLen
        int 80H
        mov eax,1
        mov ebx,0
        int 80H
        nop
```

I know that there might be an error in the `sub ecx,SnipLen` since it gives me a different output. The output before fixing it is `BEEP_BOOP
UNKNOWN_REGISTER` and the output after fixing that line is `BEEP_BOOP
MALFUNCTION`.

Comment: So what is the problem? That line is perfectly fine. What beep boop? Malfunction? Where/how/what? Which LCD screen?

Comment: `add byte [ecx],af` cannot be right. "I don't know how to use assembly language": SO is not a tutorial site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hoax post. The code does not print either of those messages, after correcting the code error it prints a spoof message.

Comment: According to a deleted (non)answer, "This code is the last question of https://go.cyber-fasttrack.org"

Answer (score 4):

DoMore: add byte [ecx],af

this is wrong, you are calling register section af which doesn't exist. it needs to be al. 
3 years later it is fixed, hope you figured this out before now. <3

Answer (score 0):

you probably better use C to solve this problem, for it's just a singleliner there:

printf ("FLAG:YOU'R_FUNNY_AREN'T_YOU?\n");

Comment: can I know how you got that answer?

Comment: because I have to get it through correcting the assembly code

Comment: @AdoobII you have already been told which line the error is on. The clue is in what the registers are (not) used for.

Comment: I don't quite understand you,the line `add byte [ecx],af` contains an error as `Rad Lexus` said but I am not entirely sure what I have to fix.

Comment: @WeatherVane I got it!, so there are 32-bit registers and 16-bit registers, and `eax` can only take `al` or `ah` registers

Comment: i changed  add byte[ecx], al ... ax is 6 (and growing), so it could only be al; if ax is < 256, ah is 0

Answer (score -3):

```
;  Clicking button saves & builds using commands:
;    nasm -f elf -g -F stabs evil.asm
;    ld -o evil evil.o
section .data
Snippet: db "@E9>06G@Q:CN3C57I<)<)*"
SnipLen: equ $-Snippet
section .text
global _start
_start:
        nop
        mov ecx,Snippet
        mov edx,SnipLen
        mov eax,6
DoMore: add byte [ecx],al
        inc ecx
        inc eax
        dec edx
        jnz DoMore
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        sub ecx,SnipLen
        mov edx,SnipLen
        int 80H
        mov eax,1
        mov ebx,0
        int 80H
        nop
```

Comment: If you're going to post an answer that differs from the question by one character, it would be pretty helpful of you to post an explanation of what you have changed, and how it helps to solve the problem (for other readers, it's the last character of the `DoMore` line that has changed).